# Can agent causation be a “primitive”?

Tags: causation

When we say that the ball falls due to gravity, we don’t ask for why gravity exists or how exactly gravity causes the ball to fall down. And if there is a mechanism, sooner or later we accept one of those deeper mechanisms as brute facts that have no explanation. Further questions are presumed meaningless.

But if someone says that God caused X, we presume it has no explanatory power, since we search for a mechanism. But doesn’t this presume that only mechanistic explanations can be brute facts? If we can’t ask further questions about mechanistic explanations, or if we can with an answer of “it’s brute”, why can’t we do the same for agent explanations?

Can one say that God caused X without a mechanism at all?

A rebuttal to this I can think of is the idea of causal closure and because the effects are physical, a physical explanation seems to be the last stage of whatever explanation leads to a physical effect. It may make no sense to have a presumably nonphysical explain something since the end effect is physical.

Comment: "We presume it has no explanatory power, since we search for a mechanism". *You* search for mechanisms, the rest of us are not so fixated. Even physicists abandoned mechanistic explanation as the only form of explanation over a century ago.

Comment: This is simply not true @Conifold Most physicists do not accept “God causes X” as any form of explanation. Can you give me a type of explanation for a physical effect that doesn’t just reduce to a physical mechanism? Note that pointing to quantum mechanics doesn’t count. That would contain potential examples of no explanation, not an effect that has a different kind of explanation than a physical one. Unless you have different definitions for physical and mechanistic at which point you’re just focusing on semantics again.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Agreed although I think that observing God do X would imply the existence of a mechanism. We are not talking about whether we **know** the mechanism. We are talking about whether a mechanism exists, and nothing seems to explain a physical effect apart from a physical mechanism.

Comment: Forget quantum mechanics, classical electrodynamics is already non-mechanistic. The last mechanistic theory of it was Lorentz's aether, and that is using "mechanistic" loosely. Physics steadily moved from "particles in motion" to abstract mathematical description since 18th century to present day, and that had little to do with the issue of determinism. That aside, what you think "counts" makes no difference. Physicists accept quantum mechanical explanations as perfectly explanatory, and many non-causal explanations as well, as in Noether's theorem explaining conservation laws, for example.

Comment: @Conifold Most physicists and most philosophers both think that a radioactive atom’s decay point has no explanation. And when they do think there is a hidden explanation, it is mechanistic in the sense of a regularity or law or something else that is physical. I am not talking about the “mechanical philosophy” of the 17th century and rather referring to the idea of causal closure which almost all physicists accept. Many people use mechanism to mean a physical mechanism or method or naturalist way of explaining things.

Comment: Nah. It is just you imagining what they think, you are not around them much, apparently.

Comment: @thinkingman How is "agent" defined in the context of agent causality? I read that the concept of an "agent" being a cause is oppposed to consider an "event" as cause. But I would prefer an independent,  constructive definition, not just ex negativo.

Comment: @Conifold Name me physicists who don’t either a) think there’s no explanation for an atom decaying at a certain point or b) think there is an explanation that doesn’t just amount to another physical mechanism/law/regularity. The notion of non causal explanations are hotly debated. See [SEP Section 6](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causal-explanation-science/#NonCausMathExpl)

Comment: SEP Section 5**

Comment: The first paragraph is utterly false.

Answer (score 0):

[Explanatory power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explanatory_power) doesn't directly depend on a mechanism. The issue with God claims include the lack of a mechanism, sure, but also:

- A lack of direct observations of God doing so
- Unnecessary claims (claims that can already be explained by other causes that are otherwise accepted)
- Claims that can trivially be exchanged with other comparable claims with no change in explanatory power
- A lack of predictive power
- Unfalsifiability
- A lack of clear and rational differentiating criteria for what God did and didn't do

So yes, you can reasonably say that God did something without knowing the mechanism for doing so, but that by itself still leaves a number of issues.

Although I don't accept that "primitive" or "brute" facts is a valid thing that exists. People seem to like to use these to sneak their desired conclusion in.

A ["brute fact"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute_fact) is "a fact that cannot be explained in terms of a deeper, more 'fundamental' fact". To say that God causing something is a brute fact suggests that you have no justification for saying so, which would mean you have no reason to say that God caused it.

For a person doing something, one can say you asked them to, they heard that, and then they did it. You can say you saw them hearing you, or they explicitly acknowledged what you said. You can say that you saw them move their body in certain ways to do the thing. You might also say that you know the person exists because you can see them. If you have any of that, then I'd say you shouldn't call something a brute fact, and then we can also evaluate those reasons and whether they're good to determine whether it's reasonable to conclude what you did. And if you have none of that, how did you reach your conclusion?

#### Why you believe vs actual causation

There may be some conflation between actual causation and the justification for believing that a particular causal link exists.

Above, I was mostly talking about beliefs about causation. Explanatory power is purely about our reasons for believing something.

If we're talking about actual causation, it seems by definition true that there's some mechanism that allows a cause to have some effect, even if we don't or can't know that mechanism.

As for "primitives" in actual causation (something that can generate uncaused causes), some would say that's God - that's [the cosmological argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam_cosmological_argument) (and we can discuss the issues with that argument). Some might say that agents can also be "primitives", but that's questionable. Even most dualists should agree that you make decisions based on physical senses, memories, emotions, brain damage and mental illness. Those can all be included in the causes that led to you making a decision (as can your birth, and everything leading up to that). All dualists can really claim is that there's some additional thing in the middle which all of the above pass through, from where you make decisions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I’m a bit confused as to what situation it would be reasonable to say that God did something without a mechanism. Or do you mean without knowledge of a mechanism? Lastly, you’re right that a brute fact implies no further explanation. But this doesn’t mean they don’t exist. For otherwise, there would be an infinite regress, unless you believe in circular explanations. The rest of your answer makes sense to me.

Comment: @thinkingman "Or do you mean without the knowledge of a mechanism" - yes (edited).

Comment: @thinkingman "unless you believe in circular explanations" - something like that, but I wouldn't call them that. If I see a car insurance bill in your house, that might support the belief that the car I saw you driving is your car. And me seeing you drive that car might support the belief that the car insurance bill is for your car. Maybe that isn't the best example, but facts/beliefs supporting one another is not that uncommon, and it's arguably the foundation of [coherentism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherentism).

Comment: Interesting example. I guess I’m not fully sure how those are actual explanations though. You seeing me drive a car before might support the belief that the car insurance bill is for my car. But it doesn’t **explain** my car insurance bill and why it’s there. It may explain why you believe that the car insurance bill is for my car. But that same explanation wouldn’t explain the opposite scenario you mentioned and so there seems to be no circularity when it comes to explanation. I might need to think about this more though @NotThatGuy